# How to change mapping of one field in existed index? Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have index with mapping:

```
GET /warhammer/_mapping
```

Gives me:

```
{
   "warhammer": {
      "mappings": {
         "logs": {
            "properties": {
               "@timestamp": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "dateOptionalTime"
               },
               "@version": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "HostName": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "boosters": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "device_model": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "build_type": {
                  "type": "string"
               }....
}
```

I need to change mapping of field `device_model` to `not_analysed`!
I've tried:

```
PUT /warhammer/_mapping
{
    "device_model": { "type": "string",
    "fields": { "raw":
    { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" } } }
}
```

and this:

```
PUT /warhammer/_mapping
{
    "device_model": { 
        "type": "string", 
        "fields":
            { "raw": 
                { "type": "string", 
                    "index": "not_analyzed" } 
        } 
    }
}
```

But it gives me:

```
  {
   "error": "ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: mapping type is missing;]",
   "status": 400
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? Help please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PUT /warhammer/_mapping/logs
{
  "properties": {
    "device_model": {
      "type": "string",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```